# How to get C# null state to convert List<T?> to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nullable

I am utilizing [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) in the C# nullable context.

I am taking a `List<string>`, then transforming it to a new `List<string?>` with a `Select` like so. I then filter out the `null`s with a `Where`, but the underlying type is still `List<string?>`.

```
strings = strings
    .Select(s => method.ThatReturnsNullableString(s))
    .Where(s => s is not null)
    .ToList();
```

When I try to use this as a `List<string>`, I get a CS8619 compiler warning. An easy solution is to use the [! null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) and the warning goes away, but I try to use this as sparingly as possible.

Another solution is to use `.Cast<string>`, but I would assume this adds runtime overhead for no reason.

Have I not sufficiently proven to the compiler that the collection is of type `string`, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please put in full types in the query and include the signature for `method.ThatReturnsNullableString(s)`.

Comment: And `var strings = strings` is invalid C# code. Please give us real code.

Comment: And there is no overhead for `.Cast<string>()` as you must do it.

Comment: [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) doesn't change the type.

Comment: @Enigmativity Apologies, as I was trying to create a minimal example separate from my actual code. I have modified my example to match @Muhammad Sulaiman's answer. As for full types, ```strings``` is a ```List<string?>``` and the example method would be something like ```string Method(string? s)```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.Where(s => s is not null)` will suppress the null-only items and will keep items of type `string?`, so the result will be of type `List<string?>`.

Use `.OfType<string>()`, it will skip null values and casts `string?` to string, It's the equivalent to `.Where(s => s is not null).Cast<string>()`.

```
strings = strings
    .Select(s => method.ThatReturnsNullableString(s))
    .OfType<string>()
    .ToList(); // List<string>
```

Comment: Please test your code before posting. It's invalid C#.

Comment: Generally, this is not what `OfType` is for. You are explicitely stating result type, if source sequence changes its type, the result does not. By this approach you can unintentionally filter out things that are not null.

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman - There's nothing like testing your code. There's still a syntax error.

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman - Also, since the question is about the final type of the `newStrings` variable, I'd also suggest not using `var`.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek In this instance, my list consists only of ```string```s, but I appreciate your comment. Would you recommend the null-forgiving ! over this, or do you have a different idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think Jodrell had a good idea, it is a pattern worth making an extension. But I would use more simple API.

```
strings = strings
    .Select(s => methodThatReturnsNullableString(s))
    .SkipNulls()                
    .ToList();
```

the extension code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SkipNulls<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {                
        if (item is not null)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel a lightly cleaner version of the extension method approach is this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Denullify<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (item is T value)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

This code:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", new string?[] { "A", null, "B", }));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", new string?[] { "A", null, "B", }.Denullify()));
```

...produces:

```
A, , B
A, B
```